# Flat bar conversion - shifter is skipping a gear

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter, derailleur-rear, tiagra

I am in the middle of converting my bike with road handlebar to a flat bar.
The old road bar has a Shimano 105 brake/shifter and 105 derailleur.
Something like this:
https://www.mec.ca/en/product/5055-021/105-ST-5700-L-STI-2x10-Speed-Lever-Set

The bike is a 10 speed.

I bought some Tiagra Road flat bar shifters: SL-4700-R 10s and SL-4703-L

The Left hand SL-4703-L works perfectly.
However, the SL-4700-R right side shifts up nicely for about 4 to 6 rings, and then skips a ring.  Playing with the tension just changes which ring gets skipped.

I take it I screwed up and the new shifter is not compatible with the derailleur / cassette.

Is my only option to return the shifters and try to find something else?

Thanks!

Edit: Found a video -

Comment: Had the same issue - lots of head scratching - get an 11 speed rear mech and all should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correcto, unfortunately for you, the latest (4700) Tiagra system uses a different cable pull to previous 10-speed groupsets, therefore the shifters are pulling the wrong amount of cable for your derailleur. It won't get better, however much you change the tension.

You could get a new 4700 derailleur, which would match the shifter and work with the existing cassette, keeping the flat bar.

Comment: Tiagra 4700 strikes again!

Comment: Tiagra 4700 derailleurs are reasonably priced, too.  Especially so in the used market or new take- offs.

Comment: Or get a 105 11 speed rear mech for a couple of quid more